# Using dynamic cookie domains with Nuxt auth

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I am trying to create a single front-end site which will serve many (unlimited) domains but I'm struggling to get Nuxt auth to work with the different domains that might be used.

In other projects, I have set up Nuxt auth like this:-

```
// Auth configuration
auth: {
  plugins: [ '~/plugins/auth' ],
  localStorage: false,
  cookie: {
    options: {
      domain: '.example.com',
      expires: 7,
    },
  },
}
```

so that any subdomain of example.com will use the cookie that's set when someone logs in.

But in this case, I don't know what the domain name will be.

Does anyone know how I can set the domain of the cookie dynamically, when the user hits the page?